# split PDF and convert first page to image using php

Tags: php, pdf

I have pdf file consisting around 100 pages, my requirement is to grab it's first page and convert it into a image using PHP, beside this i have have to convert the pdf into multiple files.For instance a 100 page pdf will make 99 files + 1 image file use as cover page.

Comment: ImageMagick with Ghostscript and the right fonts can read and write PDF files same as normal images (but the resulting PDF files will be rasterized). Call ImageMagick from your PHP script and tell it what you want to do: `convert input.pdf[0] page1.png; convert input.pdf[1] page2.pdf; convert input.pdf[2] page3.pdf`...

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to do , as it reqires some postscript methods to be implemented in PHP , first wold be splitting pdf to 100 pages , then , first page should be "printed" and files reordered after that correctly.

Comment: You are right He can convert the First page in to image by using Imagick but first he need to split the all pages.

Comment: And it might have some side effects , like timestamps on end and such useless things. Reordering is not so easy , even when You do it locally , as pdf splitter doesn't recognises pages order , just throws bunch of pdf's and , if no some kind of page number OCR is present , it can give a lot of headaches.